# Handling iCloud Core Data errors

Tags: core-data, error-handling, icloud, transaction-log

I have a library-style iCloud + Core Data setup. The app I am working on contains user data that sits behind a login screen. After the user logs in, the Persistent Store Coordinator is instantiated and the iCloud store gets added to it.

Here is my use case and problem:

1) Start using the app, data is being stored to iCloud
2) Delete the app
3) Build to device again, login to the app, expect transaction logs to be recalled and to recreate data in local store.
4) When a slow connection is used, I get errors in debug log stating multiple times that the file download failed...
5) The app is empty and it now appears as if the backup recovery failed.

My configuration is indeed correct and works 100% over a descent connection.

Is there a way to force iCloud to retry downloading these files immediately? Is there a call back which I can use to make sure these files were downloaded successfully before allowing the user into the app?

Any advice will be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

iCloud is a technology still very much in its infancy, especially the integration with Core Data.

The interval at which iCloud decides to push content down to a device is unpredictable, and unfortunately at this time there is no way force iCloud to retrieve the data. Somewhere in the Apple Developer Forums it says that when iCloud content fails to download, it will simply try again later.

There is not a call back that you can use right now either, your app is will need to be (if possible) smart enough to know when the correct content as been downloaded. Depending on how much content you need, you could do some inventory by seeing what data you got from the notification:  `NSPersistentStoreDidUpdateUbiquitousContentChangesNotification` if any, and checking the userInfo dictionary for the inserted (or updated, deleted) rows.

I have been able to do a similar thing in apps, and when your situation occurs load the local store for the user and migrate the store later on to the ubiquitous one.

These are just some suggestions, your situation might be very different. Hope this at least helps in some way.